# Finding all occurences of backslash and deleting twice before every occurence of them

Tags: regular-expression, search, replace

I got some output code that has random backslashes, followed by a new line. For example:

```
( 1-z+z^11-z^12+z^22-z^23+z^33-z^34+z^37-z^38+z^40-z^41+z^43-
z^45+2*z^46-2*z^47+z^49-z^50+z^52-z^53+2*z^55-2*z^56+z^57\
-z^59+z^61-z^62+z^64-z^65+z^66-z^67+z^68-z^69+z^74-z^76+2*z^77-2*z^78+z^79-z^82+z^83-z^84+2*z^86-2*z^87+z^88-z^91+2*z^\
92-2*z^93+z^95-z^96+z^97-z^100+2*z^101-2*z^102+z^103-z^105+z^107-z^109+2*z^110-z^111+z^114-2*z^115+2*z^116-z^117-z^118\
+2*z^119-z^120+z^123-2*z^124+2*z^125-z^126-z^131+2*z^132-2*z^133+z^134-z^137+2*z^138-z^139-z^140+2*z^141-2*z^142+z^143\
-z^146+2*z^147-z^148+z^150-z^152+z^154-2*z^155+2*z^156-z^157+z^160
```

I want to remove all the backslashes and newlines so that it's all on one continuous line. I was thinking the way to do this would be to move the cursor to before each backslash occurrence, and then hit delete twice. Is there a way to automate this on Vim so it searches the entire document and does it for all cases? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can substitute nothing for *backslash-followed-by-newline* throughout your buffer:

```
%s/\\\n//g
```

See [`:help :substitute`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/change.html#:substitute).

Comment: When I try using this, it says that there is no \\\n

Comment: Are you using Vi as opposed to Vim? If not, are you opening the file with the correct encoding?

Comment: If you have trailing spaces use `%s/\\\s*\n//g`